# Can I use a Message queue to sit between my application and external system to track everything which goes out?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have a spring-boot app which does some processing. This app sends out requests, communicates with different applications. The requests include

- HL7 messages to tcp/ip socket of an external system.
- http requests to other API's(Not every API call but selected one's)
- json data to file system

I would need a mechanism to store everything that's gone out and track them, such that if I need to resend something I should be able to manually resend them. And also to make sure something which is sent out eventually goes out to the endpoint.

I had a look at Message brokers/Message queues - RabbitMQ, Kafka, ActiveMQ. I haven't worked with any of these. These queuing frameworks from my understanding provide pub/sub mechanisms, direct exchange modes.

My questions

- In a Messaging environment, can I send a message to a broker and then have the broker send to an external endpoint?
- Does the consumer be connected to the MQ or subscribed to it for receiving messages? Can't the broker just push a message to the       receiver.
- If the receiver is an restful API, can it just receive the request without any MQ specific consumer code written? I cannot ask the    external system to write some consumer code.

I initially assumed I could use message brokers for this purpose. But later after the analysis have come to the conclusion that Message brokers are not suited for my case. Is my assumption correct?

Alternate solution,
Add an entry to the database along with the payload for every request/message that goes out of the system. Build an UI which can be used to track these requests and provide a resend option in the UI which can be used to resend these messages to the endpoints. Looking at around 200000 requests/messages being sent out per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only requirement is resending failed messages, you can use a simple message queue like RabbitMQ to queue the failed messages. Then develop a separate service to subscribe to the above queue and resend messages it receives.

If you are expecting to grow your service with more requirements, then go for Kafka.
But whatever the message broker you chose, design it like this.

1. Processor service (can be your existing spring boot app) - this will process and results will be published to the message broker.
2. Kafka/RabitMQ/ZeroMQ - this is just a queue which holds your messages
3. Integration service - this will subscribe to the above message queue and send whatever requests it received. Failed messages can be re-queued to Kafka for later processing.

This way, you don't have to ask 3rd parties to implement your logic and you will have more control over the integration.